# "Ein guter Weg" vs "Eine gute Art und Weise"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> *Ein guter Weg*, um Deutsch zu lernen, ist mit Muttersprachlern zu reden und deutsche Zeitungen zu lesen.
>
> *Eine gute Art und Weise*, Deutsch zu lernen, ist mit Muttersprachlern zu reden und deutsche Zeitungen zu lesen.

Ist `eine gute Art und Weise` besser als `ein guter Weg`? Ist das zweite idiomatisch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für meine (muttersprachlichen) Ohren gehen beide Varianten.

- Wählt man "**Weg**", schwingt etwas stärker mit, dass das Lernen ein Prozess ist, bei dem die Fähigkeiten schrittweise (Ha! Gleiche Metapher!) wachsen,
- bei "**Art und Weise**" betont man, ebenso wie bei "**Methode**", die Herangehensweise an den Lernprozess etwas stärker.

Alle drei sind idiomatisch, die Unterschiede minimal.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung! Das wußte ich nicht. Ich dachte, sie haben die selbe Bedeutung:(

Comment: Die Unterschiede sind sehr gering - bei flüchtigem Hören fällt das den meisten nicht auf. Das geht schon fast in Richtung Literaturkritik ;-). Aber Deutsch als Sprache kann eben relativ fein in Bedeutungsnuancen unterscheiden - wenn man es so benutzen will. Auf Englisch, z.B. fällt mir das oft deutlich schwerer. (Ironischerweise nicht in diesem Fall, "approach" und "method" funktionieren gleich.)

Comment: Gebongt! Danke sehr!

Comment: @DerPolyglott33, Tipp: "Gebongt!" bedeuted  "Ok!" / "Agreed!", nicht "Ah, I get it!" -  Du meinst vermutlich  "Kapiert!" oder ganz flapsig "Geschnallt!" / "Gerafft!". Gebongt kommt ursprünglich aus der Buchhaltung, ein Bon ist ein Beleg (receipt), der "verbucht", also in die Bücher (accounts) eingetragen und verrechnet werden muss  - also "gebongt".

Comment: Axo. Danke nochmal